# How can I open a Markdown file in preview mode by default in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, markdown, preview

I'm trying to configure a GitPod or GitHub Codespace so that the README.md gets automatically opened in preview mode at boot time.

I managed to open the file as:

```
code README.md
```

but that opens the editor, I'd like to open it in preview only mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you google "`github vscode issues markdown open preview by default`", you will probably find this issue ticket pretty high up in the search results: [Option to automatically open markdown in preview
#54776](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54776). Quoting Matt Bernier from [their comment there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54776#issuecomment-1090859620):

> To change this, you can configure the default editor for .md files (or whatever other markdown file extension you wish). Here's an example setting:
>
> ```json
> "workbench.editorAssociations": {
>     "*.md": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor"
> }
> ```
>
> Use the [`View: Reopen Editor With...`] command to switch back to the standard text editor.

---

There's also another related issue ticket about opening the Markdown preview to the side by default: [Automatically Activate Markdown Preview #2766](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2766). If you're interested in that one too, give it a thumbs up to show support, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress, but please avoid noisy comments like "+1" or "bump".